# Clear all in a multi-select drop down

Tags: multi-selection, combobox

i'm designing a form that includes this multi select combo box. by default all the options in it are selected. but when filling the form the user will be required to select 1-2 options. this form would have around 30 options in it.

in order to do this the user will probably need to clear the form. i'm curious whats the best way to clear the options in the combo box once the user has opened it. maybe some kind of clear all button, but how would it be within the combo box

[image]

Comment: I am wondering why all the checkboxes are selected by default, if users commonly only select one or two? It seems the default setting does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Have a main 'checkbox' that controls the behavior of child checkboxes and then change its state based on user actions -

[image]

Hope this helps!